# Why is there no an simple way to define a many to many relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I was trying to do a many to many relationship between two classes using EF Core 2.0, by simply having an ICollection of the other in each class.

This seems to work just fine in in EF 6 ([see this tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)). Why does this not work in EF Core?

```cs
public class ClassA {

   [...]

   public ICollection<ClassB> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB {

   [...]

   public ICollection<ClassA> As { get; set; }
}
```

I found a way to do this in EF core ([see this tutorial](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)), but this looks like more manual work than it needs to be.

Does anyone know if they are planning to support this any time soon?

Comment: use a list like this ->   public List<ClassA> As { get; set; }

Comment: I just cant imagine how a many to many relationship should work without an intermediator table, at least if you dont want to store the ids comma separated in one column. Maybe newer EF versions try to make this step opaque?

Comment: I already did that. When I try to do the migration the following error occurs: ```Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ClassA.ClassB' of type 'List<ClassB>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating' ```

Comment: @RaphaelMayer EF6 did it without a join table, EF Core requires you to specify the join entity. (well, at least until EF Core 3 is released hopefuly)

Comment: @DavidG but how? Storing the relations comma separated? Lets say i have a table books and category, i would need multiple book entries for every category, and multiple category entries for every book. This doesnt work. Thats why an intermediator table is needed. Maybe EF6 created some kind of invisible one?

Comment: @RaphaelMayer No, EF6 would just do this all internally for you.

Comment: @RaphaelMayer Take a look at the first tutorial I liked in the question. They automatically create a join table.

Comment: Ok thats what i thought ("invisible one") :) thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please See This Link: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity core was supposed to provide many-to-many relationship without mapping table as from the **3.0** release.
You can follow the github ticket [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508).

Waiting for this feature, the workaround is to use a join table as an Entity. See the workaround explained on the github discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368#issuecomment-69207820).

**EDIT** 
As Ivan point it out, this feature status is still in backlog and could or could not be part of 3.0 version or higher (as for 05/2019).

Comment: As far as I am aware, this feature is hopeful for EF Core 3, but not guaranteed.

Comment: @DavidG That's what I understood too. It is **supposed** to provide from 3.0. However, the already available 3.0 preview does not allow to do so for now. As far as I know.

Comment: The current status is `backlog`, which means it's not scheduled for any release. Also does not guarantee it will be addressed at all. All it guarantees is that it *might* be addressed some day.